# iPhone app testing on iPad seems to fail (nothing happens)

Tags: iphone, ipad, testing, ios7

My questions is in regards to an app designed for iPhone being available on the iPad/iPad Mini.

In the past I've been able to test .ipa files on an iPad and they've just appeared in the "2x zoom" mode, which is what I want.

When my testers try and add my latest .ipa to their iPads they now get a greyed out app icon which, when clicked, says "installing" and then nothing happens. I tried setting my iPhone app to "universal" target, this allows the app to be dragged to an iPad but the GUI is all botched and I'm trying to avoid making a new GUI just for iPad.

So, my question is: "Is this the way things are in the latest iOS/iTunes?" and "Do I have to create a new GUI if I want it to be available on the iPad as well as iPhone?"

I can test directly from xCode onto my iPad and it works in the 2x zoom mode, looks fine and does the job. So why is it different when it comes to using the .ipa system for users without xCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISSUE SOLVED

Well, I say solved. I simply set my target to 6.1 rather than 6.0 and it worked. The icon now appears on my iPad Mini and works. The mini is running 7.0.3.